# Segue Back to Self View Controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I am currently facing a problem that I wanted to segue back to the same view controller by click on a table view cell. For your information, my table view is generated programatically and each of the cells are using NIB files to control.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if( indexPath.row == 0 ){
         NSLog(@"Clicked");
    }
}
```

When I clicked on the cell at position number 0, the log does came out. So now I wanted to segue back to the same view controller instead to the others. From the storyboard, it is impossible for me the drag the segue it is because the view controller is only have a scroll view.

E.g: Inside View Controller A have 5 cells, when I clicked on the first cell, it will segue back to View Controller A and pass data.

Please advise ya if you need to see more of my codes. Thanks viewer!

Comment: did you push or present the view through segue?

Comment: nope, I can't create any of the segue from my storyboard cause there is no action button or cells there. And everything I created programatically.

Comment: why do you want to segue back to the same view?

Comment: yes, this is what I want to do, which is segue back to the same view. According to what I know, if we trying to create a segue in storyboard, we must have an object that can fire event. E.g: a cell or a button.

Comment: i mean why do you want to segue to the same view.... segue is meant to use when it is required to jump to another view

Comment: it is just simply because of trying to reduce redundant codes? and it is a a lot LOL

Comment: I've got the same issue. I'm attempting tree traversal using UITableViews. Using segues, I have to create duplicate views on storyboard and have them loop each other. LAME. Segue to self would do the trick.

Comment: I found a solution that worked for me. See below.

Answer (score 14):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select a row in your tableView and have it performSegueWithIdentifier back to this same/current UITableViewController?

To do this:

1. In *storyboard*, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag from the exposed table view cell to the yellow view controller icon in the black bar below. This creates the segue to self view controller.
2. Click on the *segue*, and add an identifier; e.g. "segueToSelf"
3. In your *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* method, add the following:

   `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSelf" sender:self];`

Comment: Thanks for this, got it opening on itself now.  However I replaced Step 3 with `prepareForSegue:sender:` which works well too.